# Problem installing tidyverse in R 3.6.2 - no jsonlite

Tags: r, macos, installation, tidyverse

I am trying to install tidyverse after updating R for mac. I am using Mac OS Catalina 10.15.2

When installing, I get the following error message:

```
* installing *source* package ‘jsonlite’ ...
** package ‘jsonlite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘jsonlite’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/jsonlite’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘jsonlite’ had non-zero exit status
```

And when trying to load tidyverse. I get the following error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘jsonlite’
```

I tried to install jsonlite as a seperate package, first uninstalling tidyverse, but got this error message:

```
  package ‘json’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)
```

Now at a bit of an impasse. Anyone know how to resolve this issue

Comment: You can try to install the `jsonlite` package first, then try to install `tidyverse` again.

Comment: Does this help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254380

Comment: yup, tried the jsonlite install after uninstalling tidyverse first

Comment: Was that "yup" to Bappa, meaning "try to install it again"; or was it to me, that the link I provided answered your question and you can now install `jsonlite` and subsequent packages with no problem?

Comment: 'xcode-select --install' did the trick. thanks.